# FullText Search: Latency Issue - Not showing results

Tags: google-app-engine

We are a premium account user. We are running the FullText Search feature in production for the past 3 days. Found the following weird behaviour in fulltext search while accessing the results via the application as well as text search viewer.

**field1 = (value1 OR value2 OR value3) AND field2 = (value4)**

Didn't return any results either from the application or the text search viewer which is weird because the data was created and indexed as a document successfully.

Then I tried the following in the viewer by removing the field1 filter,

**field2 = (value4)**

It showed up the result in text search viewer successfully.

Finally i tried the first query again which has the extra filter which is this,

**field1 = (value1 OR value2 OR value3) AND field2 = (value4)**

It showed up the results in the text search viewer successfully.

The same first query which is shown above gave results via the application also after that.

Why didn't the first query give the results when i tried for the first time both in text search viewer as well as via the application?

Please give us a direction as how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Regards,
Anantha Krishnan

Comment: Is it possible this is a consistency issue? How long after data insertion before you tried the first query. While I haven't looked at the docs in a while, I never saw any mention about what kind of consistency the search api actually offers.

Comment: Hi,

Document was indexed successfully at 12:00:09 (UTC) and the request for search came in at 12:00:45 (UTC), 12:01:47 (UTC), 12:01:49 (UTC), 12:03:08 (UTC) & 12:03:24 (UTC).

There was no instance restarts during these time.

Only in the last request came in at 12:03:24 (UTC), the results came successfully (1 record found) and the other 4 requests for search which came after indexing the document failed to return results (ie...0 records found was the result being returned).

Please let me know if you need any other information regarding this.

Thanks.

Regards,
Anantha Krishnan.